# Linq and entity framework distinct on non-primary key value

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I have table 1 which contains part numbers only.

I have table 2 which contains part numbers along with many other fields relating to it which I all need to get.

I need to get all parts from table 2 which don't have a part number in table 1.

I need to also get distinct part numbers from table 2. Part numbers is not the primary key in table 2. Table 2 has over 3 million records so multiple statements might not be smart.

```
context.Parts.Where(x => !partmasterids.Contains(x.PartNumber)).ToList();
```

This should achieve all the criteria except getting distinct returns.

`context.Parts.GroupBy(x => x.PartNumber).Select(x => x.First()).Where(x =>` `!partmasterids.Contains(x.PartNumber)).ToList();`

I have tried the above LINQ statements and moved around the groupby to after the where statement but it will not work.

I either get errors with First(), FirstOrDefault will run endlessly. Distinct doesn't even work. I am not sure how to write the correct LINQ statement.

Comment: Can you please provide Table 1 and Table 2 entities classes?

Comment: Another alternative, not much different but... context.Parts.Where(x => !parmasterids.Any(y => y == x.PartNumber)).DistinctBy(x => x.PartNumber).ToList()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already have TableA in `partmasterids`?

And the missing parts (TableB-TableA) from the statement you have above: 
`var missingParts = context.Parts.Where(x => !partmasterids.Contains(x.PartNumber)).ToList();`

Would the distinct partnumbers then be simply TableA union (TableB-TableA)?

```
var allPartNumbers = partmasterid.Union(missingParts.Select(p=>p.PartNumber)).Distinct();
```